# javascript pointer function

Tags: javascript, function, pointers

if I have:

```
function init(t,y,u) 
{
   alert(t + " " + y + " " + u);
}

// String.prototype.add = init(5, 6, 7);  // 1)   
// window.onload = init(5,6,7); // 2)
```

in the 1) `init` will be executed and then it pointer assegned to `String.prototype.add`
but in the 2) the function is only executed one time... but why not two times also
when the `onload` event is raised?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens with your code:

- Defining a function called init with three parameters that will be alerted when the function is called.
- Calling the function init with parameters 5,6,7 (an alert will popup) and assign the result (undefined) to String.prototype.add
- Calling the function init with parameters 5,6,7 (an alert will popup) and assign the result (undefined) to window.onload

If the code above was executed before the window.onload event was fired, nothing will happen when it is fired, because it is set to undefined.

Answer (score 8):

> in the 1) init will be executed and then it pointer assegned to String.prototype.add

No it won't. The function will simply be executed and its return value (`undefined`) will be assigned to `String.prototype.add`. No function pointer will be assigned. To do this, you need to *return* a function!

```
function init(t,y,u) {
    alert(t + " " + y + " " + u);
    return function () { alert('function call!'); };
}
```

Comment: To return itself: return arguments.callee;

Answer (score 5):

You may want something like:

```
String.prototype.add = function () { init(5, 6, 7); };
```